# How to sum textbox in gridview row using javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have gridview which in the cell contains a textbox and a checkbox. By default, textbox is disabled. It will be enabled when checkbox in same cell checked. And it will sum the total value in a row. I can make it enabled and disabled. I also can sum the total only if textbox enabled by default.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" class="data" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                            <br />
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" class="chk" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" class="data" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                            <br />
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" class="chk" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" class="rowTotal"></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                //code to enable/disable textbox
                $(".chk").on("change", function () {
                    if (this.childNodes[0].checked) {
                        this.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.disabled = false;
                    }
                    else {
                        this.previousSibling.previousSibling.previousSibling.disabled = true;
                    }
                });

                //code to sum row value but didn't work if textbox disable from the first
                //$(document).ready(function () {
                //    $(".data").keyup(function () {
                //        var temp, total = 0, index;
                //        $(this).closest("tr").find(".data").each(function (i, item) {
                //            temp = parseFloat($(item).val());
                //            if (!isNaN(temp))
                //                total = total + temp;
                //        });
                //        $(this).closest("tr").find(".rowTotal").html(total);
                //    })
                //});
            </script>
```

I expect the total when checkbox checked and when user change the value in textbox.

Comment: one solution is create one function to fetch all the checkbox which been enabled, inside this function add all text box together, and bind this function to all check box and text box change event

Comment: @beibeizhu Thanks. Logically, I have same idea. But, I can't make it into code. I'm just starting using javascript.